God-breathed or God-breath - present or past-tense?
Most interpretations say "God-breathed" in 2 Tim 3.16. But, on what basis? It is an adjective in NFS.
Edit: NFS = nominative feminine singular

And that from a child thou hast known the holy scriptures, which are able to make thee wise unto salvation through faith which is in Christ Jesus. All scripture is given by inspiration of God, and is profitable for doctrine, for reproof, for correction, for instruction in righteousness: That the man of God may be perfect, throughly furnished unto all good works. [2 Timothy 3:16 KJV]


The word is formed from the Greek word for God and the Greek word for 'to breathe'. Thus the English verb form (the past participle) is used 'breathed'. Nouns can be used as adjectives (a defence facility),  participles too. Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and Help, below, as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.

Thanks Nigel.
Two questions: are you suggesting it is ambivalent whether the word is past or present?
Also, apologies if I violated part of the guidelines/etiquette of this site

No, you did not violate anything ; it is standard to invite new users to see the Tour and the Help. I think the past tense is used since Paul is referring to scripture that was written in the past (the Hebrew scriptures, I suggest) since, in context, he refers to Timothy's childhood experience. I have edited simply to add the text under consideration and to show you how to highlight quotations. (I do not know what 'NFS' refers to, so please re-edit if you wish.)

Short Answer: "Theopneustos" tells us what the scriptures are—divinely inspired—but it does not provide information about when this inspiration took place.
The word of interest is "theopneustos" ("God-breathed"):
It combines both "theos" (God) and "pneó" (To blow, to breathe) to form a compound adjective.

Compound words occur when two or more words combine to form one
individual word or a phrase that acts as one individual word. [1]


An adjective is a word that modifies or describes a noun or pronoun.
Adjectives can be used to describe the qualities of someone or
something independently or in comparison to something else. [2]

Tense is a feature of verbs. They tell us when an action occurred (past, present, future).
"The green car" - "green" is an adjective describing the car, but it doesn't tell us when the car is green.

The term "theopneustos" is used to describe something that is divinely
inspired or given by the breath of God. [3]

"theopneustos" ("God-breathed") is an adjective that describes the nature or the quality of the scripture rather than a specific moment in time. It's saying that the scripture is inspired by God. Their origin is divine. That is the quality that they have.

Helpful.
If the scriptures are God-breathed, does the Spirit remain within each word? "My words are spirit and life?"
Can we say that the Spirit is irrevocably from the scripture?
If the scriptures are inspired... can we say that they are in-spirit, or in-[the]-Spirit?

@Calvin those are good questions. You might ask that as separate from this one. I take this as meaning that his words are meant to bring spiritual transformation and eternal life to those who believe and follow them.

The word used in 2 Tim 3:16 is θεόπνευστος (theopneustos) and is an adjective and unique in the NT.  It is a compound word consisting of two parts:

θεός (theos, "God")
πνέω (pneō, "to breathe")

Thus, the word means "God-breathed" or "God-inspired".  Peter expresses the same idea using different words:

For no such prophecy was ever brought forth by the will of man, but
men spoke from God as they were carried along by the Holy Spirit.

See also Acts 28:25-27, Heb 3:7.  Now, just how this works and the details are another matter that is debated.

Thanks Dottard.
So are you suggesting, both God-breathED and God-breath are both legitimate interpretations? Meaning it can be understood past-tense and present?

@Calvin - It is an adjective and so does not have tense.

So you are saying at minimum that it cannot be God-breathED b/c adjectives do not have tenses? Or are you purposely avoiding the quesiton b/c it is safer... and at times wiser not to answer. E.g. the Orthodox refuse to say whether the Spirit could proceed from the Son.

@Calvin - I am saying that the word means "God-breathed" as an adjective.  It does not have tense as does a verb.  That is a grammatical fact.  However, the fact that the inspired Scripture exists, means that however it was produced is a past completed act.

Thanks @Dottard. Agreed that the scriptures were spoken and canonized in the past. They are complete. But not on grammatical terms from this word. My larger question is whether the scriptures are The Spirit's continued breath... a fascinating inquiry, if only for me.

@Calvin - that is a theological question and not a hermeneutical question.  However, John 16:13 says that it is the Spirit of Truth = the Holy Spirit that guides into all truth.  Thus, I believe that the enlightenment of the HS is essential to understand the Bible.
